# Distribution of random numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's assume I'm generating N random numbers in the range [1..M].

How many numbers in the range should I expect would get generated exactly 0 times?

My rationale is that you can take any given number in the interval and view it as a Bernoulli trial, which makes it's chance of being generated exactly 0 equal to:

```
P(generated 0 times) = (1 - 1/M) ^ N
```

Now, the probability above is the chance for ANY given number in the range to be generated exactly 0 times, so intuitively this means that after generating the N random numbers approximately `M * P(generated 0 times)` numbers should be generated 0 times. After making experiments it looks like the intuition above is correct, but I'm curious on what's the mathematical proof for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To justify your calculation, invoke the Linearity of Expectation.

Specifically:  Let $X_i$ be the indicator value for $i$.  That is, $X_i=1$ if $i$ is missing from your sample and $X_i=0$ if it is present.  Then $\sum X_i=X$ is the number of missing indices, so you want to compute $$E[X]=E\left[\sum X_i\right] =\sum E[X_i]=M\times (1-\frac 1M)^N$$